# Using Camel JCachePolicy with Caffeine in OSGi Blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, typesafe-config, caffeine-cache

I want to apply a [camel-jcache](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/jcache-component.html) route policy using a Caffeine cache in OSGi Blueprint. That policy allows to enclose a Camel route or part of a route with a caching facility, which ensures that the result of whatever happens within the route policy will be cached. Consider the following route:

```
<route id="my-konfig">
    <from uri="direct:my-konfig"/>
    <policy ref="jCachePolicy">
        <toD uri="... some enrichment call..."/>
        <transform>
            ... expensive transformation...
        </transform>
    </policy>
</route>
```

However, when I add a cache configuration to the blueprint like this:

```
<reference id="cachingProvider" interface="javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider"/>
<bean id="caffeineCacheManager" factory-ref="cachingProvider" factory-method="getCacheManager"/>
<bean id="caffeineCache" factory-ref="caffeineCacheManager" factory-method="getCache">
    <!-- see src/main/resources/application.conf for cache expiration policy -->
    <argument value="konfig-cache"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jCachePolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.jcache.policy.JCachePolicy">
    <property name="cache" ref="caffeineCache"/>
    <property name="keyExpression">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.model.language.SimpleExpression">
            <property name="expression" value="${exchangeProperty.typNr}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

then the blueprint bundle fails to start with a `NullPointerException` at `BeanRecipe.setProperties`.

I was able to track this down to a classloader problem. I am asking for a cache named `konfig-cache`, but the configuration for that cache is located in a file *application.conf* in the bundle resource (the [default location](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior) for custom config in Typesafe Config). The OSGi runtime fails to load that file with the default classloaders.

How can I define the classloader which Caffeine's underlying [Typesafe](https://github.com/lightbend/config) Config should use to locate the configuration file in the resource of the Blueprint bundle?

The related dependencies in *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</g
    <artifactId>jcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And in my Karaf *feature.xml*:

```
<feature version="${camel.version}">camel-jcache</feature>
<feature version="${camel.version}">camel-caffeine</feature>
<bundle>mvn:com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/jcache/2.9.2</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:com.typesafe/config/1.4.2</bundle>
```

Finally, my *src/main/resources/application.conf*:

```
# Configuration for camel-caffeine in HOCON format
# see https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#hocon-human-optimized-config-object-notation
# see https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior
# see https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/jcache/src/main/resources/reference.conf
# see example https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/jcache/src/test/resources/application.conf
caffeine.jcache {

  konfig-cache {
    key-type = java.lang.String
    value-type = java.lang.Object

    # The eviction policy for automatically removing entries from the cache
    policy {
      # The expiration threshold before lazily evicting an entry. This single threshold is reset on
      # every operation where a duration is specified. As expected by the specification, if an entry
      # expires but is not accessed and no resource constraints force eviction, then the expired
      # entry remains in place.
      lazy-expiration {
        # The duration before a newly created entry is considered expired. If set to 0 then the
        # entry is considered to be already expired and will not be added to the cache. May be
        # a time duration or "eternal" to indicate no expiration.
        creation = 60m
        # The duration before a updated entry is considered expired. If set to 0 then the entry is
        # considered immediately expired. May be a time duration, null to indicate no change, or
        # "eternal" to indicate no expiration.
        update = 60m
        # The duration before a read of an entry is considered expired. If set to 0 then the entry
        # is considered immediately expired. May be a time duration, null to indicate no change, or
        # "eternal" to indicate no expiration.
        access = null
      }


      # The expiration thresholds before eagerly evicting an entry. These settings correspond to the
      # expiration supported natively by Caffeine where expired entries are collected during
      # maintenance operations.
      #eager-expiration {
      # Specifies that each entry should be automatically removed from the cache once a fixed
      # duration has elapsed after the entry's creation, or the most recent replacement of its
      # value. This setting cannot be combined with the variable configuration.
      #after-write = null

      # Specifies that each entry should be automatically removed from the cache once a fixed
      # duration has elapsed after the entry's creation, the most recent replacement of its value,
      # or its last read. Access time is reset by all cache read and write operation. This setting
      # cannot be combined with the variable configuration.
      #after-access = null

      # The expiry class to use when calculating the expiration time of cache entries. This
      # setting cannot be combined with after-write or after-access configurations.
      #variable = null
    }

    # The threshold before an entry is eligible to be automatically refreshed when the first stale
    # request for an entry occurs. This setting is honored only when combined with the
    # read-through configuration.
    #refresh {
    # Specifies that active entries are eligible for automatic refresh once a fixed duration has
    # elapsed after the entry's creation or the most recent replacement of its value.
    #after-write = 30s
    #}

    # The maximum bounding of the cache based upon its logical size
    maximum {
      # The maximum number of entries that can be held by the cache. This setting cannot be
      # combined with the weight configuration.
      size = 10
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CaffeineCachingProvider](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/jcache/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/jcache/spi/CaffeineCachingProvider.java#L90) allows to pass a classloader to `CachingProvider.getCacheManager(URI uri, ClassLoader classLoader)`.

The expected URI is simply the FQCN of the CaffeineCachingProvider.

Now for the classloader. In OSGi blueprint we can determine the classloader of the blueprint bundle and pass it to `getCacheManager`. The blueprint spec defines a number of [environment managers](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.blueprint.html#d0e87086) with predefined reference names, among others the blueprint bundle itself, which goes by the name `blueprintBundle`.
Since we are using Camel anyway, we can use Camel's BundleDelegatingClassLoader to simplify access to the bundle's classloader:

```
<bean id="caffeineCacheManager" factory-ref="cachingProvider" factory-method="getCacheManager">
    <argument value="com.github.benmanes.caffeine.jcache.spi.CaffeineCachingProvider"/>
    <argument>
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.core.osgi.utils.BundleDelegatingClassLoader">
            <argument ref="blueprintBundle"/>
        </bean>
    </argument>
</bean>
```